# double tap in cocos2d

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to develop a game with cocos2d. I am stuck now.I don't know how to detect the double tap event, just like the double click in windows. I try to use the

```
NSArray * allTouches = [touches allObjects];
int count = [allTouches count];
```

in `ccTouchesEnded`

But this seems to work when double touches happen at the same time. I want to what it's like in Windows.

Could anyone give me some idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer can be set up to test for double taps, see: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 3):

If you use a targetedTouchDelegate, you can do this:

```
- (void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(touch.tapCount==1) MPLOG(@"ONE TAP");
    if(touch.tapCount==2) MPLOG(@"TWO TAPS");
    return;
}
```

You will get the two touches when a double tap happens, ie this will log both "ONE TAP" and "TWO TAPS" when there is a double tap. Up to you to figure out your state and do your thing.

Comment: You are a legend.  What a great solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You talking about multi touch 2 finger tap OR double click like in mac and windows?

If it is double click like in mac and windows then here is solution.

You can do it in two ways.

1. Use UITapGestureRecognizer (set to detect double taps) Suggested by LearnCocos2D in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895613/how-to-find-if-a-view-is-tapped-more-than-2-times-within-certain-time-period-in/14896063#14896063).
2. Use manual double tap tracking by using time difference.

//decalre this in interface file

```
 NSTimeInterval      mLastTapTime;
```

In Implementation file:

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
         mLastTapTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

//in touch method

```
NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
NSTimeInterval diff = currentTime - mLastTapTime;

if(diff < 0.5 ) //0.5 or less
{
     //double tap
}

mLastTapTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```