# How to find if a view is tapped more than 2 times within certain time period in cocos 2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I am developing a game in cocos 2D. In my game I need to tap my view a certain number of times. If the user attempts to tap the view beyond the limit, it should display an alert.

Please can someone help me to find number of taps on the view. Most important is number of taps is not simultaneously. In the Total game the user can tap only a certain number of times, after which they should not tap the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with NSTimeInterval.

```
    //decalre this in interface file
    NSTimeInterval      mLastTapTime;
```

.

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
         mLastTapTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    }
    return self;
}
```

//in touch method

```
    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval diff = currentTime - mLastTapTime;

    if(diff < 0.3 )
    {
         //do whatever you want if user press with 0.3second
    }
    mLastTapTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
```

Comment: alternative: UITapGestureRecognizer (set to detect double taps)

Comment: Thanks it works for me.. But how will i limit the number of taps for a  view

Comment: Not getting what taps limitation you talking, If it is to block multi touch then use this call in AppDelegate.m: [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];

Comment: How will i set the number of taps required without adding TapgestureRecogonizer.

Comment: why to set number of taps? if time between tap is very less then its double tap otherwise consider it as single tap.

Answer (score 0):

As LearnCocos suggested you can simply use a tap gesture recognizer.  it takes a variable number to taps and/or touches to fire.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapLimitRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapLimitRecognizer:)];
[tapLimitRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:6];

[self addGestureRecognizer:tapLimitRecognizer];
[tapLimitRecognizer release]; // if not using arc.

-(void)tapLimitRecognizer:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapLimitRecognizer
{
...add your alert view here
}
```

Comment: Actually am using cocos2d. In that i add just one line of code  [self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];
Response after Touch touch action code will be in this method- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}